# Replacing values that fail a match test using Python's regex library

Tags: python, regex

I have a very large string consiting of a series of numbers separated by one or more spaces.  Some of the numbers are equal to -123, and the rest can be any random number.

```
example_string = "102.3  42.89  98  812.7  374  5  -123  8  -123  13  -123  21..."
```

I would like to replace the values that are not equal to -123 with 456 in the most efficient way possible.

```
updated_example_string = "456  456  456  456  456  456  -123  456  -123  456  -123  456..."
```

I know that python's regular expression library has a sub method that will replace matching values quite efficiently.  Is there a way to replace values that DO NOT match?
As I mentioned, this is a rather large string, coming from a source file around 100MB.  Assuming there's a way to use re.sub to accomplish this task, is that even the correct/most efficient way of handling such problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regular expression to replace everything but specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221224/python-regular-expression-to-replace-everything-but-specific-words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(^|\s)(?!-123(\s|$))-?[0-9.]+(?=\s|$)
```

It looks for the start of string or a space, not followed by -123 and space of end of string (using a negative lookahead) then some number of digits or a `.`, followed by either a space or end of string.

Then you can replace with `\g<1>456` to turn all those numbers into 456. The `\g<1>` in the replacement preserves any space captured by the first group.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9Hu5wu/1)

In Python:

```
import re
string = "102.3  42.89 -1234 98  -812.7  374  5  -123  8  -123  13  -123  21 -123"
print re.sub(r'(^|\s)(?!-123(\s|$))-?[0-9.]+(?=\s|$)', '\g<1>456', string)
```

Output

```
456  456 456 456  456  456  456  -123  456  -123  456  -123  456 -123
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/RIGDMV75452)

Answer (score 1):

You could match only the numbers between whitspace boundaries and the use re.sub with a callback function to check if the match is not `-123`. If it not, relace it with `456`

```
(?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind to assert what is on the left is not a non-whitespace character
- `-?` Optional `-`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional part that matches a `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not a non-whitespace character

Example

```
import re
pattern = r"(?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)"
s = "102.3  42.89  98  812.7  374  5  -123  8  -123  13  -123  21"

print(re.sub(pattern, lambda m: "456" if m.group() != "-123" else m.group(), s))
```

Result

```
456  456  456  456  456  456  -123  456  -123  456  -123  456
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aReSQ7/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5JQSTf)